# OnClick event for TModel3D

Tags: delphi, onclick, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I am using Delphi XE5 and I have firemonkey application. there is a Viewport and I put an instance of TModel3D and loaded an object from Obj file (it is a simple object. extruded hexagon) which created in 3dsMax.
I wrote OnClick function for this object with a simple ShowMessage(''); but it doesn't trigger when I click on it. OnClick is working fine for TCube, TSphere, ...
How can I have OnClick event and other events like OnMouseMove and OnDblClick for TModel3D?

Thanks.

Comment: After thinking about this problem I come up with a funny idea. I put a cube in the Model3d object that I had, and set the size of this cube that it can't be seen in viewport. now I write events for this cube which can not be seen. and when I click on Model3d object the event handler for that cube executes. but I think it is not a definite solution for this problem.

Comment: I'm also waiting for answers.. coz tmodel3d have onClick on its event.... I use Xe6 and also it still did not work...

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter your 3D model is OBJ or ASE or DAE the onClick event did not work.

All of the mouse events and Cursor properties within tmodel3d is not working.

This problem never been solved by Embarcadero since 2012 (Xe3 maybe). Its more like permanent bug of FireMonkey - Delphi.

You may also read : 
https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=442911&tstart=0#442911

Comment: Problem can be solved. but there is a lot of other things that they should do and this is not on the top list. for now I am using the way that I mentioned in the comment in top. but maybe when I got enough time I myself start to solve the problem basically.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do so ? Is it using tcube ? if using tcude, then that's the same with I'm doing now...